# Ruby On Rails - new migration and model change causing migration failure

Tags: ruby, rails-migrations

I've created a new migration to add a new table. Lets call it 
new_items which creates a new table.

in the migration, i've specified that the relationship with another table

```
t.belongs_to :parent
```

In my model,

```
class NewItem < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :parent

class Parent < ApplicationRecord
has_many :new_items, :dependent => :destroy
```

So when I run all migration from scratch, there is a failure on an older migration
"could not find table 'new_items'"
in the failed migration, this is the line that where the problem lies

```
def up
 Parent.where(name: "TestName").destroy_all
end
```

there is something wrong with my Parent model, as when i remove this following line it runs to completion

```
has_many :new_items, :dependent => :destroy
```

I know the issue is with the relationship between Parent and NewItem, but not sure how its best fixed

I can kinda see why its happening, but not sure how to resolve it while still keeping the relationship between the tables

Answer (score 2):

Whenever using your ActiveRecord models in migrations, it is wise to define them within these migrations, so any changes to your models in the future won't break old migrations.

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord; end
```

or in a nicer way, if your class does not need to do anything

```
Parent = Class.new(ApplicationRecord)
```

added inside your migration class should fix your issue.

Side note: if you simply want to delete all the records from `parents` table, it would be better to call `Parent.delete_all` in your migration. This would also solve the issue, but adding models to migrations is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use ActiveRecord models in the migration. ActiveRecord doesn't like when Ruby class and schema doesn't match. And it can happens if multiple migration need to be run.

I suggest to only use SQL queries in migration.

```
def up
  execute <<-SQL
    DELETE FROM parent WHERE name = "TestName";
  SQL
end
```